# I want to calculate a value that would represent the duration between 2 timestamps in the loki log line

Tags: logging, timestamp, grafana-loki

2022-07-28 00:19:44 Ana-Utils279
{"message": "Loaded ana_model", "timestamp": "2022-07-27T18:49:44.682875Z", "level": "INFO", "module": "Ana-Utils", "process": 279}

2022-07-28 00:19:44 Topo-Utils279
{"message": "Filtering out small font text from LW", "timestamp": "2022-07-27T18:49:44.326452Z", "level": "INFO", "module": "Topo-Utils", "process": 279}

2022-07-28 00:19:44 Topology-Inference279
{"message": "topology processing doc..", "timestamp": "2022-07-27T18:49:44.289498Z", "level": "INFO", "module": "Topology-Inference", "process": 279}

2022-07-28 00:19:44 Topo-Utils279
{"message": "Subscribed to Topo Update channel", "timestamp": "2022-07-27T18:49:44.260830Z", "level": "INFO", "module": "Topo-Utils", "process": 279}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720466/add-2-fields-in-logql-to-use-within-aggregate-function

similar issue

Comment: By the way i figured it out anyways 

Comment: is there a chance to see how you did that for the legacy?